# java inputting multiple strings into method

Tags: java

Thanks for checking out my question.

I have three generic strings of integers and characters that have been read from a text file. lets say:

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String filename = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("You have loaded file: "+filename);

    File file = new File(filename);
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

    String element1 = inputFile.nextLine();
    String element2 = inputFile.nextLine();
    String element3 = inputFile.nextLine();
```

The goal of the program is to take each string, check for input errors, parse results for characters and integers, and just prints stuff. How would I get the program to do this for the two remaining strings?

example input:

```
1 e 4 5 8 7 e 5
1 4 4 f 5 6 8 1
7 8 2 8 3 7 2 8
```

my expected output for each string:

```
System.out.println("stuff :" +someInt);
System.out.println("stuff :" +someInt);
System.out.println("stuff :" +someString);
System.out.println("stuff :" +someString);
```

I understand this concept with integers:

```
int result = someCalculation(someint, someint, someint, someint );

public int someCalculation(int num1, int num2, int num3, int num4)
{
    int result=(((int) num1)*5*56*2)+(((int) num2)*54*2)+(((int) num3)*3)+((int) num4);
    return result;
}
```

I'm looking for something like this in main() which would take string element 1, then element 2, then element 3, and input the string into a method.

```
myExpectedOutput = myCalculations(element1);
myExpectedOutput = myCalculations(element2);
myExpectedOutput = myCalculations(element3);
```

I want something like this where each element can be inputted into the method and then it will return the print statements.

```
public void myCalculations(String element1) //
{
    String newElement= element1.toUpperCase();
    String[] tokens = newElement.split(" ");

    String part1= tokens[0];
    String part2= tokens[1];
     . . . .
    String part6= tokens[6];
    String part7= tokens[7];
    boolean game = true;
    try
    {

        do 
            {
            for (int i=0; i<tokens[0].length(); i++) { 
                c = element1Upper.charAt(index); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
            etc etc


    System.out.println("stuff :" +someInt);
    System.out.println("stuff :" +someInt);
    System.out.println("stuff :" +someString);
    System.out.println("stuff :" +someString);
```

Comment: can you please be more specific about the data stored in the string? do you have a structure? or do you want the method to find a structure for you? without these details, method cant check errors, cant create structure etc.

Comment: I hope that helped. I added some of my code and how I want the method to work. I think its just a bit of syntax. I need to insert each string into the method, the method takes the string, does some parsing and further calculations, then prints the expected output. I've already done the parsing and calculations, i'm just looking for a generic way to input each string to get the output for each.

Comment: I think you had it there in your example. Since your calculation methods doesn't return anything, you want just `myCalculations(element1);` instead of `myExpectedOutput = myCalculations(element1);`

Comment: even after your edit it is still not clear. what do you mean with "parse results for characters and integers"? what is your expected output for your expected inputs? does "1 e 4 5 8 7 e 5" converts to [int:"1",char:"e",int:"4587",char:"e",int:"5"] ? what about others?

Comment: @Yilmaz Durmaz "parse results for characters and integers" I mean parse element 1, element 2 etc.  The element1.toUpperCase line is how I want to use the string, then there is 350ish lines doing stuff, then I want the print statements to return to the user. Next, I want to do the same thing with element 2, element 3 etc and just print back each time

Comment: you are still not clear as you haven't clarified WHAT IS YOUR EXPECTED OUTPUT from this method. you have 3 different example input, having different amounts characters surrounded by ints. what do you want exactly? I am not interested what your program does, I try to give you what you need, which is the parsing function. for example should "1o0"  convert to ["1","o","0"] or should give an error being a type for "100"?

Comment: return String.format("%d : %d : %d", someInt, someInt, someInt); i guess? I dont need a parsing function, i need to input multiple strings called element1, element2 etc into the parsing function then print the result

Comment: do you have a CONSTANT structure for that string of yours??? if so, you can use the very same method you used for integers. If not, that is what I am asking, you need to parse your input string to get strings and integers out of it. I might give you a string composed of hundreds of such variables, and method could parse them all, only if you have definite conditions on what the output should look like. if you have only a few variables then you can delete this question as you can do it the way you do with integers.

Comment: Hi, please make the question more clear, try to clean up the code to get [mcve] because its really unreachable to get where are you pointing, thank you. Also `do` block is not needed in your code example. Code inside will be executed just once everytime in this case.  Please make it easy - `from keyboard you are getting file path? then you try to load every line- or the count is defined before?   With data from file are you trying to do what, where it should be?` Please also notice more code / text in question doesnt mean better quality ..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you can solve this by letting the myCalculations method return a list of strings and then you can loop over that list to print each string.

```
public List<String> myCalculations(String element) {
  List<String> printList = new ArrayList<>();

  //parsing and calculating here

  //when adding a print string you do something like
  printList.add(String.format("stuff : %d", someInt));
  // or
  printList.add("stuff :" + someString);

  //return list
  return printList;
}
```

And use this like

```
List<String> list = myCalculations(element1);
for (String str : list)n {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Here is my suggestion on how the workflow could look

```
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

List<String> inputList = new ArrayList<>();
while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
  inputList.add(inputFile.nextLine());
}
//other stuff?

for (String element : inputList) {
  List<String> list = myCalculations(element);
  for (String str : list)n {
    System.out.println(str);
  }
}
```

Of course if you want to print it all together or do something else with the output before printing you could gather all output into one large list

```
List<String> allOutput = new ArrayList<>();
for (String element : inputList) {
  allOutput.addAll(myCalculations(element));
}
//use allOutput later...
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for! How does it cycle through string elements though?

Comment: I wasn't sure what you wanted for that so I left it out, basically you can choose to have an loop outside of the myCalculations method and call it for each element or you change the input parameter to be a list and have the loop inside. It mostly depends on how you want your output, in the first case you can print the output separately for each input (element) and in the second all output will be returned at once so you print everything together.

Comment: @Smurf1, I have updated my answer based on my previous comment

Comment: @Smurf1, if this is what you want, you don't even need to add "stuff:" in every list element as you can add it later in print loop. And again if it is what you need, then accept it as the answer to your question. If not, please make you question clearer as I tried to explain.